# How to write bash & sql files to setup users for postgres?

Tags: sql-server, linux, bash, postgresql, shell

I am trying to create bash and sql files to create a user and a database..

Here is what I have done so far..

***Setup_postgres.sql***

```
Create USER dummbyuser;
 ALTER USER dummbyuser with superuser;
 ALTER USER dummbyuser with LOGIN;
/q
```

***Setup_postgres.sh***

```
sudo su - postgress
psql -f setup_postgres.sql;
sh setup_postgres.sql
logout
```

**My problem [SOLVED]**

I tell bash to run the Setup_postgres.sh however it hangs after the
*sudo su - postgres* line The  setup_postgres.sql does not run at all.

Any one have any ideas on what I am doing wrong ?
Is this the right approach ?
I have very little experience writing bash files.

**Is it possible for the script prompt users for the name of *"dummbyuser"***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are starting a new login shell for the postgres user using `sudo su - postgres`. After you exit from that shell the rest of your script will run, but not with postgres user privileges.

You could modify your script like this to get it working:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo -iu postgres psql < setup_postgres.sql
```

This will run the specified psql command with postgres user privileges.

Comment: Thank you!!! Out of curoisity what does the #!/bin/bash mean (I know it s a comment however I have seen that around) ...Also does -iu do ?...Thanks again!

Comment: The `#!/bin/bash` means that when you run the script bash should be used as interpreter for that script. `-iu` are sudo options. `-i` tells sudo to start login shell and `-u` tells it to run as specified user. You can read more details in sudo help (just type `man sudo` in the terminal).

Answer (score 0):

Also you don't need to sudo over to psql you can just run `psql -U psql < setup_postgresql.sql`  as the default is to trust the username passed. If not is passed it will use the account name it is running under.

Or you can do something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
createuser -U psql -s dummbyuser 
createdb -U psql -O dummbyuser dummbyuser
```

or even  using a shell here doc

```
psql -U psql <<EOF 
 Create USER dummbyuser;
 ALTER USER dummbyuser with superuser;
 ALTER USER dummbyuser with LOGIN;
 EOF
```

---answering question from comments---

you can use positional arguments to such as `$1` and `$2`

so for example if your script was called `build_sql.sh` you could right it like this

```
#!/bin/bash
createuser -U psql -s $1 
createdb -U psql -O $1 $2
```

and then call it like  `./build_sql.sh  dummbyuser dummbybd`

which would replace `$1` with `dummbyuser` and `$2` with `dummbydb`

or you can prompt the user for input and capture it using the `read` command

so the same `build_sql.sh` script could become

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "please enter username followed by [enter]" 
read user 
echo "please enter db_name followed by [enter]" 
read dbname 
createuser -U psql -s $user 
createdb -U psql -O $user $dbname
```

then if you want to be really fancy you can combine them

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
      user=$1
else
  echo "please enter username followed by [enter]"
  read user
fi
if [ "$2" != "" ]; then
  dbname=$2
else
  echo "please enter db_name followed by [enter]"
  read dbname
fi

 createuser -U psql -s $user 
 createdb -U psql -O $user $dbname  

 echo "created new user $user, and gave them a db called $dbname"
```

Comment: Awesome Thankyou! I got it to run perfectly. One question I have for you is do you know how to ask for user input for the "dummbyuser" ?....My group is going to run this script and I would like them to enter there user name without editing the file. Thanks Again!!